# If $\mathbb f$ is analytic and bounded on the unit disc with zeros $a_n$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\lvert a_n\rvert\right) \lt \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, roots

I'm going over old exam problems and I got stuck on this one.
Suppose that $\mathbb{f}\colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and bounded. Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be
the non-zero zeros of $\mathbb{f}$ in $\mathbb{D}$ counted according to multiplicity. Show that 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 - \left|a_n \right|\right)\lt\infty $$ 
I can understand that $\left|a_n \right|$ goes to $1$ since zeros are isolated, but it doesn't help showing the series is convergent. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is known as *Blaschke's condition* and is in fact also true for functions in the so called Nevanlinna class. The simplest way to prove this is using Jensen's formula.

Assume $f \in H^\infty$. You may as well assume that $f(0) \neq 0$ and that $f$ has infinitely many zeros. Let $n(r)$ be the number of zeros in the disc $D_r$. Fix any integer $k$ and choose $r < 1$ so large that $n(r) > k$. By Jensen's formula,
$$
|f(0)| \prod_{n=1}^{n(r)} \frac{r}{|a_n|} = \exp\left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \log|f(re^{i\theta})|\,d\theta \right).
$$

Hence (if $|f(z)| < M$ on $D$):
$$
|f(0)| \prod_{n=1}^{k} \frac{r}{|a_n|} \le |M|.
$$

In other words
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{k} |a_n| \ge \frac{|f(0)|}{|M|} r^k
$$
for *every* $k$. Letting $r \to 1$ and $k\to\infty$ it follows that
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n| \ge \frac{|f(0)|}{|M|} > 0,
$$
which implies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-|a_n|) < \infty$.

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds :)

Comment: How do you know that the infinite product converges?

Comment: @Rick: the partial products are decreasing (and by the argument above bounded away from $0$).

Answer (score 8):

First, assume $f(0) \ne 0$. Let $r < 1$ and $n(r)$ be the number of zeros of $f$ inside $\overline{D}(0, r)$. Let $k$ be a positive integer so that $k < n(r)$. By [Jensen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula):
$$
\left|f(0)\right| \prod_{n=1}^{n(r)}\frac{r}{\left|\alpha_n\right|} = \exp \left\{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \log\left|f(re^{i\theta})\right|\right\}
$$

Since $f$ is bounded (say by $M > 0$), we have:
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{k}\left|\alpha_n\right| \ge \frac{\left|f(0)\right|r^k}{M}
$$

Now, by letting $r \to 1$, we get:
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\alpha_n\right| \ge \frac{\left|f(0)\right|}{M} > 0
$$

Which implies that:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 - \left|\alpha_n\right|\right) < \infty
$$

Finally, if $f(0) = 0$. Put $f(z) = z^m g(z)$ where $g(0) \ne 0$ and apply the reasoning above to $g$. Since $g$ and $f$ have the same zeros apart from $z = 0$, the result follows for $f$.

Comment: Amazing timing with two almost identical answers!

Comment: @mrf Amazing indeed. And this isn't the first time I see it happen!

Comment: Thank you very much for both of you. The answer and timing is amazing!