# A detail in the proof of Blaschke's condition via Jensen's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve the following problem from Stein's complex analysis.

> Suppose that $\mathbb{f}\colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and bounded. Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be
> the non-zero zeros of $\mathbb{f}$ in $\mathbb{D}$ counted according to multiplicity. Show that
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 - \left|a_n \right|\right)\lt\infty $$

I have found a solution in MSE, as in [If $\mathbb f$ is analytic and bounded on the unit disc with zeros $a_n$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\lvert a_n\rvert\right) \lt \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/394909/134639) and [A holomorphic function with infinitely many zeros in the unit disc](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2894071), and following the lines I have proved that $\Pi_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|$ converges, but I can't see why this impies $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 - \left|a_n \right|\right)\lt\infty $, and have been stuck here for hours. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/394909/305862

Comment: @JeanMarie I've read the linked question and answers too, but they all seem to regard this step as trivial. So I guess it is something quite simple, but I couldn't grasp it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is highlighted in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria). Essentially, if $\prod |a_n|$ converges to say $p$, then $$\log p = \sum \log |a_n|  = \sum \log (1 + (|a_n|-1)),$$

and by limit comparison the convergence of this last series is the same as the convergence of $\sum (|a_n| - 1)$.

Comment: Thanks! So a simple limit comparison does the trick!